# jbehave example table creates a javaw task and doesn't purge it

Tags: memory, jbehave, javaw

I am using an Example table in my Jbehave story, and I notice that after each run, a new Java process is created and has not been purged.
In my Windows task manager, I can see a "javaw" task, with a memory of 1.4Mo. Because these tasks are not purged, the OS becomes rapidly very slow. I have to kill these tasks by hand.

The problem doesn't happear if I don't use example tables in my story.

Is it a bug from Jbehave ?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it was a problem at our side. A custom FreemarkerProcessor was defined, and there was an error that caused an infinite loop, preventing the jbehave process to end. The multiple javaw tasks were dues to the jbehave processes, that never ended.
It is fixed now.